# How to append to a bootfile using do_deploy in Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, device-tree, yocto-recipe, yocto-wic

this is a question for BitBake / Yocto on the Kirkstone branch (4.2). I am trying to append to a config.txt (for a Raspberry Pi) in my custom layer meta-x under meta-x/recipes-bsp/bootfiles/ using an `rpi-config_git.bbappend` file.

I have seen online that I should be using the `do_deploy_append()` function for this, but in Kirkstone in throws an old override syntax error:

```
ERROR: /home/hal/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-bsp/bootfiles/rpi-config_git.bb: Variable do_deploy_append contains an operation using the old override syntax. Please convert this layer/metadata before attempting to use with a newer bitbake.
ERROR: Parsing halted due to errors, see error messages above
```

Replacing this with a simply `do_deploy()` removes the error, but results in the contents of my do_deploy function completely overwriting the related config.txt instead of appending to it. I cannot find any reference to a new alternative to `do_deploy_append()` in the Yocto docs.

Below is the contents of the `rpi-config_git.bbappend` file:

```
DEPENDS:append = " linux-raspberrypi"
DEPENDS:append = " dtc-native"

inherit deploy

do_deploy() {
echo "dtoverlay=x-y-overlay" >> ${DEPLOYDIR}/bootfiles/config.txt
}

addtask deploy after do_compile
```

Is there an alternative to `do_deploy_append()` since this seems to have been deprecated, or is there an entirely new mechanism I am unaware of, or is this not desired behavior?

My goal is to add a device tree overlay assignment in the config.txt without editing the meta-raspberrypi layer.

Comment: There was a small syntax change recently for overrides. It is now `do_deploy:append()` and not `do_deploy_append()` (`:` vs `_`)

Comment: Also, you can find some documentation about this here: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/migration-guides/migration-3.4.html#override-syntax-changes

Comment: Ahhh I see, thank you very much I'll keep this in mind, hadn't found those docs